# GemNotFoundException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am receiving this error when trying to run rails server:

```
$ rails server
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:317:in `bin_path': can't find gem rails ([">= 0"]) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

Why does 1.9.3 use 1.9.1 lib folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Does 'bundle exec rails server' work?

Comment: It does. Can you explain why that is or what I can do to not have to type that every time? Thanks so much.

Comment: Depending on how you've got things installed, ruby might not always be able to find gems.  This happens to me especially when I've got a gem direct from a git repository for example.  Bundler can find all those gems and either loads them or adds the necessary ENV paths so ruby can.  I've never looked into the specifics.

Comment: Getting this trying to set up a new project. Do I have to bypass commands for everything?

rails --version
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:317:in `bin_path': can't find gem rails ([">= 0"]) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
 from /usr/local/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'

Comment: Looks like it.  You might want to give RVM a try.  I rarely have to prefix my commands...

Answer (score 0):

It uses 1.9.1 for compatibility and historical packing reasons. Given the change is only in minor numbers, everything just works. IMO this folder could be called just ../ruby/1.9.